# Vue2: How is reuse existing directive in my custom directive?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Code for my custom directive:

```
Vue.directive('position', {
    // When the bound element is inserted into the DOM...
    inserted: function (el) {
        // exist directive v-sors

    }})
```